# Having trouble returning a value from an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scope

I am writing a calculator program that allows the user to turn on the calculator by pressing an ON button. This triggers a function that changes the variable `calcStatus` to `true` and displays a temporary message. However, if I press the ON button a second time, the same function that displays the temporary message runs even though the value for `calcStatus` should be `true`. What am I doing wrong? (I read somewhere that this is called an anonymous function so that might be contributing to the problem)

Also, am I doing this efficiently or is there an entirely better way to write the code I have now?

```
$(function(){

    function main(calcStatus){
        if (calcStatus == true) {
            // WILL RUN IF CALCULATOR IS ON
        }
        else {
            $('.button_on').click(function(){
                calcStatus = true;

                $('.screen_text').html("CALC ON");
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.screen_text').html("");
                }, 500);
                return calcStatus;
            });
        }
    }

    main(false);
})
```

Thank you in advance for your help! This is my first time posting a question so hopefully I did it right!

Comment: Won't do you any good to return anything but `false` in a Event Listener... Unless, of course, you're trying to stop the rest of the function from executing. Events are asynchronous. Maybe you should use a Promise?

Comment: calcStatus is a flag that indicates whether the caclulator is on or not.  You need to persist the value, so make calStatus a higher order variable with global scope, dont pass it into the function as an argument.

Comment: The language doesn’t work like that. Your `if` statement is only relevant during the one and only time you invoke `main()`, at which point `calcStatus` is `false` and the `else` clause is used. The event listener is created and unless you explicitly remove it, it will trigger on every event, not just the first. The surrounding `if` statement has no relevance to the actual event handler itself.

Comment: @Lennholm Thank you for your advice! I'm relatively new to js so I'm still learning the ropes. How can I explicitly remove the event listener?